# .NetCore IOptions configure object with constructor

Tags: .net-core, configuration

In a .NetCore application I want to inject into a service a setting that has some custom logic in the constructor. In particular, I have a setting section looking similar to this:

```json
"Email": {
    "FromEmailName" : "My name",
    "FromEmail" : "my_name@mydomain.com"
}
```

Now, I'd like to bind this to a class looking like:

```cs
public class EmailSettings {
    public System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailAddress { get; } 
 
    public EmailSetting(string fromEmailName, string fromEmail) {
        MailAddress = new MailAddress(fromEmail, fromEmailName);
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I see that the `EmailSettings` class must have a parameterless constructor, but is there any way that I can overcome this problem by introducing an 'intermediate' class `UnparsedEmailSetting`, and then do something like the code below?

```cs
public static void BindEmailConfig(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
    var section = configuration.GetSection("Email");
    services.Configure<UnparsedEmailSettings>(section);
    var emailConfig = section.Get<UnparsedEmailSettings>();
    var emailSettings = new 
    EmailSettings(emailConfig.FromEmailName, emailConfig.FromEmail);
    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(emailSetting); // does not work
    services.RemoveConfiguration<UnparsedEmailSettings); // method does not exist
}
```

Comment: Is the actual problem that you need to set the property `public System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailAddress {get;} ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118252/4949005) from [Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2855798/jakob) will work fine, but it won't give you the services that `IOptions` can provide (such as reloading). If that is important and the information in your question is complete you should be able to do a work-around. Otherwise I strongly suggest [Jakobs approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69118252/4949005).

Keep the settings:

```
  "Email": {
    "FromEmailName": "My name",
    "FromEmail": "my_name@mydomain.com"
  }
```

Register your config like so:

```
services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Email"));
```

And change your model:

```
public class EmailSettings
{
    public string FromEmailName { get; init; }
    public string FromEmail { get; init; }

    public System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailAddress => new MailAddress(FromEmail, FromEmailName);
}
```

That way you don't need any special logic in your constructor. In <s>C#10</s> [C#11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#required-members) you should be able to add `required` to the property as well.

```
public required string FromEmail { get; init; }
```

The downside is that your new `EmailSettings` will expose more members than necessary. But it will still be immutable.

If it's important to also not expose any other members you can simply add an interface:

```
public interface IEmailSettings
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress MailAddress { get; }
}
```

And change your registration like so:

```
services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Email"));
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<IEmailSettings>>(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailSettings>>());
```

Now you can inject `IOptions<IEmailSettings>`. Or you can change the registration to `IOptionsMonitor` if you want to enable reloading.:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<IEmailSettings>>(sp =>
{
    return sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<EmailSettings>>();
});
```

Comment: `required` properties didn't make the cut for C# 10.0, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dai - Yes. You're right. I updated the answer and added a proper link.

Answer (score 4):

Since adding an option basically means adding a singleton of type `IOptions<TOptions>`, you can do that. There is no constructor for Options, but you can use [the create method from the Options extensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/Options.cs).

```
services.AddSingleton<IOptions<EmailSetting>>(serviceProvider =>
{
    return Options.Create(new EmailSetting(Configuration.GetSection("Email").GetSection("FromEmailName").Value,
                    Configuration.GetSection("Email").GetSection("FromEmail").Value));
});
```

It can then be injected as usual with `IOptions<EmailSetting>`.

Comment: Future readers : here is a shorter version the above. (but UPVOTE for sharing the extension method) //start-code// -->     MyCustomConfigObject mcco = /* however, where-ever you want to compose this thing */        ; ; ; ;           services.AddSingleton(_ => Options.Create(mcco));                     <--  //end code//